# "How to fix 'mosquitto package' errors " on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, mqtt, yum, mosquitto, aws-iot

I am preferring this [link[1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-bridge-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-aws-iot/)] AWS doc to bridge my RPi3 as mqtt-IoT gateway with AWS IoT core.
But got these errors.

```
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: systemd
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

And I can't use "mosquitto" command after logged into Amazon Linux AMI. How to remove these errors?

I have already used thses two options.

```
--skip-broken
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But they didn't work for me.

I have also installed mosquitto package in my RPi3 board.

```
pi@rpi3:~ $ mosquitto -v
1558004586: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date Wed, 13 Feb 2019 00:45:38 +0000) starting
1558004586: Using default config.
1558004586: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1558004586: Error: Address already in use
```

It is working in it locally. But can't make a bridge with AWS.

In short in that whole doc, Due to mosquiotto package issue, only these two commands are not working properly for me.

`sudo yum install mosquitto mosquitto-clients`

```
sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/bridge.conf –d
```

Comment: Please do not post images of errors, post the actual text and format it properly. Images are hard to read and impossible to search for.

Comment: k, pics removed, any idea about my issue.?